# How to display panorama images with Pannellum

Tags: javascript, html

I have a panorama image and try to display it on my website with auto-rotate. Pannellul https://pannellum.org/documentation/examples/auto-rotate/ works great but the only downfall is that it's 360.

I am looking for something similiar to this https://liviucerchez.com/panorama360/example3/ but not a wordpress plugin. Something portable.

Any tips or suggestions would be great. Everytime I google, only 360 panorama appears, which is not what I'm quite looking for, I am trying to have the image only be able to move from left to right, right to left. **No vertical movements.**

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```js
pannellum.viewer('panorama', {
            "type": "equirectangular",
            "panorama": "main-image.jpg",
            "preview": "preview-image.jpg",
            "autoRotate": -2,
            "hfov": 100,
            "vaov": 100,
            "vOffset": 0,
            "minPitch": 0,
            "maxPitch": 0,
            "pitch": 0,
            "showZoomCtrl": false,
            "keyboardZoom": false,
            "mouseZoom": false,
            "minHfov":100,
            "maxHfov":100,
        });
```